# How do you test service or controller methods in grails 2.3

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I'm just starting out with grails 2.3 and I have problems getting the unit tests to run. What I've done so far is I've run

```
grails create-app new-app
grails create-service NewService
grails test-app
```

This produces

```
| Running 1 unit test...
| Completed 0 unit test, 0 failed in 0m 2s
| Tests PASSED - view reports in C:\Git\aspera_web\target\test-reports
```

So far so good but if I edit the method

```
void "test something"() {
}
```

in the NewServiceSpec class to

```
void "test something"() {
    assert false
}
```

and run again I again get

```
| Running 1 unit test...
| Completed 0 unit test, 0 failed in 0m 2s
| Tests PASSED - view reports in C:\Git\aspera_web\target\test-reports
```

I then looked into the spock documentation and tried to edit my test again. This time to

```
void "test something"() {
    expect: 1 == 2
}
```

which produces

```
| Running 1 unit test...
| Running 1 unit test... 1 of 1
| Failure:  test something(aspera_web.NewServiceSpec)
|  Condition not satisfied:
false
        at aspera_web.NewServiceSpec.test something(NewServiceSpec.groovy:19)
| Completed 1 unit test, 1 failed in 0m 2s
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in C:\Git\aspera_web\target\test-reports
```

which looks promising so then the next step is to test methods in my NewService class so I again change my test to

```
def service = new NewSevice()
void "test something"() {
    expect: service.serviceMethod()
}
```

and when I run it I get

```
| Running 1 unit test...
| Running 1 unit test... 1 of 1
| Failure:  test something(aspera_web.NewServiceSpec)
|  java.lang.NullPointerException
        at aspera_web.NewServiceSpec.test something(NewServiceSpec.groovy:21)
| Completed 1 unit test, 1 failed in 0m 2s
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in C:\Git\aspera_web\target\test-reports
```

just for good measure I also added a test directly from the Spock exmaples

```
def stack = new Stack()
def "size"() {
    expect: stack.size() == 0
}
```

Which works like a charm...

So at last my question:

- How do I test my own service/controller methods (I get the exact same result if I replace create-service with create-controller)

**EDIT**

Apparently this is a bug in Grails 2.3.0 see my answer below.

Comment: You'll have to instantiate the service object in order to use it in the test. The expect rhs should evaluate to a Boolean.

Comment: My english is not what it should be but dont I instantiate my service with def service = new NewService() or what do you mean?

Comment: Indirectly yes. It's likely that the framework and/or the annotation creates an instance of the object that you can then reference so I doubt that you need to manually instantiate the object but the Service does not exist from reading the stacktrace.  Who advised that this should be logged as a bug?

Comment: Like I mention in the bug report when I remove the @Transaction annotation then the service gets instantiated by the framework and everything works just fine thats why I reported it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to go into the generated service class and remove the @Transaction parameter. Then for some reason the service variable in the test gets instantiated.

I've filed a [JIRA report](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10538) about it.

**Workaround**

Just remove the annotation and add the line

```
static transactional = true
```

to the service instead to get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

As you realized, Grails 2.3 comes with Spock for tests instead of JUnit. I suggest you to look [at the basics](https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpockBasics). If you want class level attributes, look at the "Fields" session.

There's also a [repository of examples](https://github.com/pschneider-manzell/grails-spock-examples) that you can check. Looking at the [service example](https://github.com/pschneider-manzell/grails-spock-examples/blob/master/test/unit/grails/geb/spock/service/GuttenbergServiceSpec.groovy) you can see that your test already have a variable called "service" that Grails define when you use the `@TestFor` annotation.

```
@TestFor(NewService)
class NewServiceSpec {

  def "some description of what the test should do"() {
    expect:
      service.serviceMethod() ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed my test to 
    void "test something"() {
        expect: service.serviceMethod()
    }
and changed the serviceMethod to return true but I still get 
| Running 1 unit test...
| Running 1 unit test... 1 of 1
| Failure:  test something(aspera_web.NewServiceSpec)
|  java.lang.NullPointerException
 at aspera_web.NewServiceSpec.test something(NewServiceSpec.groovy:18)
| Completed 1 unit test, 1 failed in 0m 5s
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in C:\Git\aspera_web\target\test-reports

Comment: Share your full test, please.